# Error "_IframeMessenger_get Target Origin is not defined" when starting the project. Autodesk Forma SDK

Tags: javascript, sdk, autodesk

I want to launch my Forma project. I found a repository with examples and settings on GitHub, but when I launch hello-world, it throws an error. How can I fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE7JH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vc05.png)

I searched for the origin configuration, but I didn't find anything. I tried VPN, it didn't help either